# Join 3 tables on same primary key

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables trips (trip_id, trip_name), events (event_id, trip_id, event_name) and images (image_id, trip_id, image_name).

I want to join all 3 tables to get events and images count for all trips. Below is the query I have used

```
SELECT `trips`.`trip_id`,`trips`.`name`, COUNT(`images`.`image_id`) as
`image_count`, COUNT(`events`.`event_id`) as `event_count`   FROM
`trips`    LEFT JOIN `images`   ON `trips`.`trip_id` =
`images`.`trip_id`    LEFT JOIN `events`   ON `trips`.`trip_id` =
`events`.`trip_id`    WHERE `trips`.`user_id` = "9"    GROUP BY
`trips`.`trip_id`
```

There is 1 trip for user_id ="9" and 1 images and 3 events corresponding to it. I am getting 3 as 'image_count` instead of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use distinct to get image count. Because there are three same image value in selected table

Comment: Thanks using distinct worked. Should I use any other join so that I get just one row for each trip?